# Can not access deployed service on K8S cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a k8s cluster with one master node and three worker nodes. The cluster is working well; when I deploy my app on the master node, it will schedule the pod to one of the nodes.
here is the YAML that I am using to deploy my app:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: s-deployment
  labels:
    app: s
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: s
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: s
        image: redis
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 23

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: s
  ports:
    - name: ans
      protocol: TCP
      port: 23
      targetPort: 23
      nodePort: 30100
```

the master sends the app pod to one of the worker nodes (for example, 192.168.10.222), and the master is on 192.168.10.221

However, I got the timed-out error when I tried to access the deployed app using postman (192.168.10.221:30100). If I use the worker's address:192.168.10.222:30100, everything is fine.

Am I missing something here?

Actually, I used to have one worker. After the master schedules the worker's app, I can access the app by using the master's address and the app's nodePort. The master can send the request to the right place. I add two more workers later, and I get the problem.

k8s :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.3", GitCommit:"816c97ab8cff8a1c72eccca1026f7820e93e0d25", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-01-25T21:25:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.4", GitCommit:"b695d79d4f967c403a96986f1750a35eb75e75f1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T15:42:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "master" node? Are you talking about the control plane?

Comment: Control Plane node was referred to as master in the earlier years of K8s

Comment: Is your 2nd worker node in "Ready" State?

Comment: Hi Erika, could you please clarify how you set up your k8s cluster (cloud provider / kind / on premise)? Do you use that 'redis' image or it is there just for an example and you use some app that listens on port 23? What k8s version are you using?

Comment: Yes, it's a control plane. I am using my local server as a k8s cluster. The Redis image is just for example.

Comment: Please, check if the NodePort service's 'externalTrafficPolicy' is set to 'Local' (describe the service).